# Print out the character, word, and line amounts using Python

Tags: python, file, character, line, cpu-word

This is what I have so far:

```
def stats(filename):
    ' prints the number of lines, words, and characters in file filename'
    infile = open(filename)
    lines = infile.readlines()
    words = infile.read()
    chars = infile.read()
    infile.close()
    print("line count:", len(lines))
    print("word count:", len(words.split()))
    print("character counter:", len(chars))
```

When executed, return the number of lines properly, but return 0 for words and character counts. Not sure why...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to go back to beginning of file with `infile.seek(0)` after you read the position is at the end, `seek(0)` resets it to the start, so that you can read again.

```
infile = open('data')
lines = infile.readlines()
infile.seek(0)
print(lines)
words = infile.read()
infile.seek(0)

chars = infile.read()
infile.close()
print("line count:", len(lines))
print("word count:", len(words.split()))
print("character counter:", len(chars))
```

Output:

```
line count: 2
word count: 19
character counter: 113
```

*other way of doing it....*:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain
infile = open('data')

lines = infile.readlines()
cnt_lines = len(lines)

words = list(chain.from_iterable([x.split() for x in lines]))
cnt_words = len(words)

cnt_chars = len([ c for word in words  for c in word])

# show words frequency
print(Counter(words))
```

Comment: Then after this, I have to check the file if it has any duplicate words , thus returning True or False, case depending. Do you know how that would be done?

Comment: why create four lists for no reason? The OP does not want the data, hey want the count

Comment: @PadraicCunningham OP wants to know more, not less.

Comment: @LetzerWille, know more about what exactly, how to write the least memory efficient code possible? have you ever heard of generators or the sum function?

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate through the file once and count lines, words and chars without seeking back to the beginning multiple times, which you would need to do with your approach because you exhaust the iterator when counting lines:

```
def stats(filename):
    ' prints the number of lines, words, and characters in file filename'
    lines = chars = 0
    words = []
    with open(filename) as infile:
        for line in infile:
            lines += 1
            words.extend(line.split())
            chars += len(line)
    print("line count:", lines)
    print("word count:", len(words))
    print("character counter:", chars)
    return len(words) > len(set(words))  # Returns True if duplicate words
```

Or alternatively use the side effect that the file is at the end for chars:

```
def stats(filename):
    ' prints the number of lines, words, and characters in file filename'
    words = []
    with open(filename) as infile:
        for lines, line in enumerate(infile, 1):
            words.extend(line.split())
        chars = infile.tell()
    print("line count:", lines)
    print("word count:", len(words))
    print("character counter:", chars)
    return len(words) > len(set(words))  # Returns True if duplicate words
```

Answer (score 2):

You have exhausted the iterator after you  call to `readlines`, you can seek back to the start but really you don't need to read all the file into memory at all:

```
 def stats(filename):
    chars, words, dupes = 0, 0, False
    seen = set()
    with open(filename) as f:
        for i, line in enumerate(f, 1):
            chars += len(line)
            spl = line.split()
            words += len(spl)
            if dupes or not seen.isdisjoint(spl):
                dupes = True
            elif not dupes:
                seen.update(spl)
    return i, chars, words, dupes
```

Then assign the values by unpacking:

```
no_lines, no_chars, no_words, has_dupes = stats("your_file")
```

You may want to use `chars += len(line.rstrip())` if you don't want to include the line endings. The code only stores exactly the amount of data needed, using readlines, read, dicts of full data etc.. means for large files your code won't be very practical

Comment: I took this approach originally but the OP added a comment in another answer that they will need to return whether there are duplicate words, so changed the words into a list.

Comment: Indeed,  a set and a flag can be used to avoid need to store any more data than necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
File_Name = 'file.txt'

line_count = 0
word_count = 0
char_count = 0

with open(File_Name,'r') as fh:
    # This will produce a list of lines.
    # Each line of the file will be an element of the  list. 
    data = fh.readlines()

    # Count of  total number for list elements == total number of lines. 
    line_count = len(data)

    for line in data:
        word_count = word_count + len(line.split())
        char_count = char_count + len(line)

print('Line Count : ' , line_count )
print('Word Count : ', word_count)
print('Char Count : ', char_count)
```